# Why am I getting Unexpected token illegal in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why am I getting the error "unexpected token ILLEGAL" in this script?  The script is supposed to retrieve all cookies and display their names and values in a table.  The error occurs on the line that has the opening table tag.

```
document.getElementById("showCookies").onclick = function(){

        var columnRight = document.getElementById('columnRight');

        var cookies = document.cookie;
        var cookiesContent = '<h1>Existing Cookies</h1>';
        console.log(cookies);
        cookies = cookies.split(";");

        if(cookies.length > 0){

            cookiesContent += '<table width="30%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                ';

            for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){

                cookieAtts = cookies[i].split('=');
                cookiesContent += "<tr><td>" + cookieAtts[0] + "</td><td>" + cookieAtts[1] + "</td></tr>";

            }

            cookiesContent += "</tbody></table>";

        }

        columnRight.innerHTML = cookiesContent;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you can't have multiline strings in JavaScript without backslashes:

```
cookiesContent += '<table width="30%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="0"> \
            <thead> \
                <tr> \
                    <th>Name</th> \
                    <th>Value</th> \
                </tr> \
            </thead> \
            <tbody> \
                ';
```

Comment: Is this common practice? I haven't seen this very often. Concatenation as shown in other answers seems to be the more common approach

Comment: It depends on whether you care about all of the extra whitespace that will be included from the indenting.  Usually people don't want it but in this case of generating HTML it doesn't matter and it's fewer non-string characters to add.

Answer (score 2):

Use string concatenation to define long strings:

```
cookiesContent += '<table width="30%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="0">' +
            '<thead>'+
                '<tr>' +
                    '<th>Name</th>'+
                    '<th>Value</th>'+
                '</tr>'+
            '</thead>'+
            '<tbody>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have line feed in your string with the  `<thead...` and that is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate this:

```
cookiesContent += '<table width="30%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="0">' +
        '<thead> ' +
            '<tr> ' +
                '<th>Name</th>' +
                '<th>Value</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>';
```

Or in the same line:

```
cookiesContent += '<table width="30%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" border="0"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
```